# Detect collision without reaction

Tags: unity, collision-detection

Okay, so this has been bugging me for quite some time now. I'm making an old school platformer type of game in 2.5D, I want objects to pass through each other, but I still want a collision to be detected.

If the player gets hit by an enemy, I just want to detect a collision for receiving damage to the player, I don't want the player to move on impact, and I just want the enemy to continue moving where he was heading.

I'm using rigidbodies and box colliders on my objects. First I thought using triggers combined with ignoring layers was the solution, but apparently trigger events aren't called when ignoring layers.

I still want to be able to use AddForce and stuff for moving objects.

Is there someway I can still utilize Unity's OnCollision.../OnTrigger.../Or other... for just detecting a collision and having no impact movement added when a collision occurs?

Have a nice day!

Comment: A trigger event will be invoked upon overlapping with another trigger. I just tested this(with one of the objects containing a rigidbody) and it worked perfectly. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "trigger events aren't called when ignoring layers"?

Comment: `Triggers` are actually do exist for this... Trigger will definitely do that for you

Comment: What you need to do is enable Trigger in your collider options and then in the script you can use: OnTriggerEnter(), OnTriggerStay() and OnTriggerExit()

Comment: @ben what I mean is that, for example my player belongs to the layer "Player" and all enemies belongs to the layer "Enemy", and in physics settings I have unchecked so that collisions won't occur between these two layers. The trigger event wasn't called, but I only had a trigger on the player not the enemy, that might be the issue I guess? I will try adding triggers to my enemies also.

Comment: @UnresolvedExternal Don't uncheck it. That means these two layers will ignore each other. You want to keep that check, because using triggers will not cause physical reactions at all(only a non-trigger collider will do that).

Comment: @Ben I have other scenarios when the player and enemies need to react on collision, so I need to ignore it between player and enemy. However, thanks to your comment I solved it by adding a child object to the player with a trigger on it and using it for taking damage, update score, etc. Dunno if it's the best solution, but it works! Thanks for the help!